# How to make `python2 -V >> myfile` "work"?

Tags: python, bash, file-io, output

I want to automatically record my python version in a computerinfo file. However

`python2 -V >> myfile`

prints only to the console but not to `myfile`. How can I get the output into a file?

Curiously, for python3 -- `python3 -V >> myfile` -- this works as I expected.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and I use the bash shell.

Comment: You need to redirect stderr, like this : `python2 -V 2>> myfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `python2 -V`, that prints the version as `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Try to redirect the `stderr` like:

```
python2 -V 2>> myfile
```